# How does Firebase Cloud Messaging calculate the amount of notifications sent?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Specifically, does it automatically remove users who disabled notifications? Does it count users who uninstalled the app?

I couldn't find any info on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging will try to deliver messages to all users that you target. So no matter if the users disabled the notifications on their phone, they will still be counted as messages that were sent.

Of course, those users will not actually receive the message, so they will not count as messages that were received/opened.

Comment: I have currently way more users than the messages that are sent when I select the whole app (1.8k users vs 1.3k users). Where can I trace back the difference? Uninstalls?